# Date Format in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, numbers, date-format

Can someone help me to format this.
in my textbox (The date is 10222012)

the output should be (The date is 10/22/2012) 
the text should be still there
thank you

Comment: Is the date part a separate variable, or is the whole text (The date is 1022012) in a single variable assigned to the TextBox?

Comment: its a whole text... its a single variable to the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of approaches off the top of my head.

If the text is coming from one variable, for example:

```
Dim MyText As String = "The date is 10222012"
```

Then you can use String functions to get the date (assuming it is always 8 characters, which can be a dangerous assumption), format it and stick it back in:

```
Dim MyDate As String = CType(MyText.Substring(MyText.Length - 8), DateTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

MyText = MyText.Substring(0, MyText.Length - 8) & MyDate
```

If on the other hand the date is in a separate variable, say a DateTime variable, you can do this:

```
Dim MyDateFormatted As String = MyDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

There are other ways to do this.  The key here is to get the date and convert it to the format you want via the [DateTime.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method, where the format string in the parantheses tells what format to use.

**EDITED**

That's what I get for not trying the code out first...if the string "10222012" isn't recognized as a valid format, there's another way to do this:

```
Dim MyText As String = dRecord.Rows(i).Item(iCount).ToString 
Dim MyDate As String = MyText.Substring(MyText.Length - 8)
MyDate  = MyDate.SubString(0, 2) & "/" & MyDate.Substring(2, 2) & "/" & _
          MyDate.Substring(4)
oSheet.Cells(x, iCount - 2) = MyText.Substring(0, _
                              dRecord.Rows(i).Item(iCount).Length - 8) & _
                              MyDate
```

It's a bit more brute force and ugly, but that should get you going in the right direction.  You might be able to get the same result use `Insert` (another String operator), but that might be just as ugly.

If you need to do this conversion a lot, I recommend putting it into a helper method, or better yet an extension method.

**2nd Edit**

You can check for blank record easily enough:

```
Dim MyText As String = dRecord.Rows(i).Item(iCount).ToString
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyText) Then
    ' convert the format here
End If
```

Comment: i use your codes but i have this error "Conversion from string "09072012" to type 'Date' is not valid." 



Dim MyText As String = dRecord.Rows(i).Item(iCount).ToString
                                    Dim MyDate As String = CType(MyText.Substring(MyText.Length - 8), DateTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

                                    oSheet.Cells(x, iCount - 2) = MyText.Substring(0, dRecord.Rows(i).Item(iCount).Length - 8) & MyDate

Comment: @Kelvz - I'll edit my answer with another way to do this.  Give me a few.

Comment: @kelvz - Updated my answer.  Let me know if it works for you.  Sorry the first one didn't, but keep in mind the formatting options available in .ToString() on DateTime objects - you'll find them useful in the future.

Comment: thanks... but there a problem "StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex"

Comment: i think "StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex" this error happen if i have black records?? i guess?

Comment: It could, yes.  You need to identify the line where it occurs (use the debugger) and then you can inspect the objects it's operating on.  I tried the code I gave you and it worked fine.

Comment: and what if i dont have any date like 09222012
(eg. no value) in my textbox. and some are like this  (The date is 10222012)

Comment: I added some code to check for a blank record.  Unfortunately, trying to do these kind of date format changes can be tricky if you do not get a consistent format or value from your data source.  You could wind up writing a whole bunch of code to cover all the common cases (and that would completely miss the edge cases) - you might be better off seeing if you can refactor the way your data is stored in your tables.  It'd be much easier if the date was stored separately (even if it's stored as an 8-digit string.

Comment: Thanks the code works ! :) but my problem is.. theres an error if some field are blank.. and some field dont contains date just txt (no value or N/A)

Comment: Glad it works.  If you have blank data or N/A, you'll have to handle those cases in the code (see my previous comment), unless you can refactor the database table.

Comment: nah.. they encode it like that. sometimes it has date some are none... so its up to me how to output it. 
Thank you.